# Adding user groups from a remote domain server to permissions of a remote desktop terminal server fails. why?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

I have 3 computers, two of which are servers running Windows Server 2008 and another running Windows 7.

One of the servers has the following roles installed; Active Directory, DHCP and DNS. The other server has a Terminal Server role installed. I am trying to log-on to the Terminal Server via Remote Desktop using the Windows 7 machine with credentials from the Active Directory server.

Sounds simple enough, right? Well, no. Whenever I try to add users or groups from the Active Directory Domain server to the Terminal Server's permissions for RDP it seems to ignore, or forget, them. Though the various methods I was able to find it either adds a strange sting of numbers after the user group or the logo to the left has a question mark on it, reopening the dialogue box replaces the user group with the name of the Domain.

I am confident I have the Domain setup correctly as I am able to log-on to users in the Active Directory from other computers I have put in the Domain, and when I attempt to browse the user objects from the Domain I am prompted with a username/password field and am able to view the structure of Active Directory objects.

Please advise.

Comment: "Terminal Server's permissions for RDP" / By that you mean "Remote Desktop Users" Group?

Answer (score 1):

When I attempt to add a user or user group to the Remote Desktop Users group it displays "domain\user (random-numbers-and-letters)" when i click Apply its removed from the list.